# How to find the number of variable received by bind_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not sure if this has been asked before,but how do we know the number of parameters that `bind_result()` receives? I tried to load data from a database and use bind_param. However, I received this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\path on line

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$id = 1;
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result_id, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);
}
```

The number of parameters in bind_result is the same number of columns in TABLE_A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470) in PHP manual for function `bind_result`, this is possible with prepared statements only when you specify all the columns in the prep. statement.

When you have prepared statement with `SELECT * FROM`, PHP does not know the number of resulting columns (you can check if this is true by trying `bind_result` with only one column variable and see if it succeeds).

So you either have to name all columns in the prepared statement (`SELECT name,addr,col3, ...`) or use the workaround in the mentioned comment - make your own function utilizing `call_user_func_array` and `result_metadata` to fetch the names and count of the columns returned.